# prestashop how to handle error: imagecreatefromjpeg(): is not a valid PNG file

Tags: prestashop

I was trying to regenerate all the thumbnails with on my local prestashop site. And i get these errors for a lot of files:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/img/p/2/5/8/258.jpg' is not a valid PNG file in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 358

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 184

Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/img/p/2/5/8/258.jpg' is not a valid PNG file in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 358

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 184

Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/img/p/2/5/8/258.jpg' is not a valid PNG file in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 358

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 184

Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/img/p/2/5/9/259.jpg' is not a valid PNG file in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 358

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ll/Documents/www/ESI/classes/ImageManager.php on line 184
```

It seems like they are corrupted...what can I do ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably because the files are (really!) JPEG files and not PNG files.

To resolve this issue, you can go to your PrestaShop Back-office in 'Preferences' > 'Images' and select 'JPG' instead of 'PNG'.

Also you might want to reconsider the choice of the PNG extension for your product pictures. In many situations it will increase the weight of the images without offering any improvements.